# Bootstrap error "jQuery is not defined" in Visual Studio 2017 react/redux project

Tags: jquery, reactjs, typescript

There's quite a lot of documentation surrounding this error but there doesn't seem to be any answers for non webpack/people using Visual Studio.

I've tried all the non-webpack related errors such as declaring jQuery on the window but nothing seems to be working, my index.tsx file is below.

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css';
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import 'popper.js';
import '../node_modules/bootstrap/js/dropdown.js';
import './styles/Site.css'
import * as React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import configureStore from './store/configureStore';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

(window as any).jQuery = $;
(window as any).$ = $;

const store = configureStore();

render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Provider store={store}>
            <Route path="/" component={App} />
        </Provider>
    </BrowserRouter>,
    document.getElementById('root'));

registerServiceWorker();
```

On load I get the error

> ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined ./node_modules/bootstrap/js/dropdown.js

I've also tried importing dropdown.js on the app component but still nothing.

It does appear to be a [webpack issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4258) but Visual Studio doesn't have a webpack config file so I can't try any of these fixes either. I'm not sure if Visual Studio uses webpack behind the scenes

Has anyone encountered this issue before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving the `(window as any).jQuery = $;` line above `import '../node_modules/bootstrap/js/dropdown.js';`.

Comment: That's got it, thanks! I thought imports were hoisted above variable declarations